# Column name documentation for npm audit --parseable?

Tags: npm, audit, npm-audit

Does anyone know where I can find column name documentation for npm audit --parseable? I can guess what about half the columns are by comparing it to the default json output, but I'm unsure on some. For example, the Y/N output in the last column.

Alternatively, is the source code available for npm audit? I didn't see it linked in the docs.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-audit

**What I Tried**:

- Looking in the docs
- npm audit --parseable --help

Answer (score 3):

They seem to have done away with this option in the latest version of NPM in favor of the --json option.  However, digging into the code here: https://github.com/npm/npm-audit-report/blob/v1.3.3/reporters/parseable.js I was able to find some semblance of column definitions.  Here's my interpretation of them (in order from left to right):

```
Package Action

Package Name

Severity Level

Remediation Action / Version

Vulnerability Description

More Info Link

Dependency Path

Breaking Changes?
```

Here's an example:
[image: Example Table Screenshot]